# Expo, use enviromental variables in app.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

Is the app.json included in the apk? I mean, if somebody unzips the apk and see my code, maybe, I will be hacked because some private keys are included in my app.json file (google maps key).

I have seen that to solve this problem, we have to use an env. file. But, how do I use my enviromental variables in app.json?

I am using 'react-native-dotenv' to manage this. And I have an .env file in my project root, with some variables like `GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY`...

Comment: If I use Expo.Constants instead, would my keys be visible in production mode?

Comment: *Is the app.json included in the apk*, not sure have you looked? I dont think it is but don't take my word for it, have never used expo

Comment: I think thats the good way. See in expo documentation that we have to write all keys there. So, I suppose that it is not included in the .apk

Comment: I really want to know this but couldn't find any information about it. Is it really safe to keep my keys in app.json? Any updates about this? I'm keeping some of my keys in dotenv but some of it needs to be in app.json (according to documents I read).